# How to correct function

Tags: python

```
test = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

def get_first_word(s):
    
    word = []
    space = False

    for i in s:
        if i == ' ':
            space = True

        else:
            if space == False:
                word.append(i)

get_first_word(test)
```

Error:

```
>>> def get_first_word(s):
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I have triple checked my indentation, I am positive that it is correct however vscode keeps saying that it is not. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Indentation is somewhat stricter in the interactive interpreter. Once any indented block (function, loop, try, if, ...) has started, you should avoid empty lines as they signal the end of the current indentation level. Unlike when interpreting an entire module at once, the interactive interpreter cannot know what comes next,  and tries to run lines as eagerly as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried getting rid of all the empty lines however it doesn't seem to be fixing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Consider removing the empty lines inside the function implementation.

When you copy and paste the above code to the interpreter, after defining the function definition, the interpreter expects function implementation. The empty line following the function definition is interpreted as end of function implementation, and since the body doesn't contain anything in it, interpreter throws Indentation Error.

To recreate the bug run the following code, for example:

```py
def a():

a()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However I tried this already, taking out all of the empty lines does not fix the error.